# Issue with publishing a new page in CQ5

Tags: aem

I have installed both `author` and `publish` instances of CQ5.5 on my PC.  But when I add a new page and publish it, it does not appear in the publish instance. Only a blank page is rendered.

I have tried activating it both from the `siteadmin` and from the `Replication` page in Tools. Only the navigation item appears in the Publish instance.

I checked the Request logs also. But it only gives a

```
200 response(OK)
```

Can someone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to activate/replicate your /apps/site folder where all of your templates and components are located to push it from your author instance to your publish instance. Activating a page doesn't automatically activate the components and templates it uses.

Go to:

```
http://localhost:4502/etc/replication/treeactivation.html
```

- Browse to or type /apps/[your site] in the path field
- Set the check boxes to fit what you want to activate (Unchecking all will make everything under the selected path activate)
- Click 'Dry Run' to see what will get activated without actually activating. (This is more of an informative step to help ensure you don't activate something not intended in a production setting)
- Click 'Activate' to activate.

You can then check your publish instance to see your templates and code are there.

It is easy to miss activating your apps folder as there is no ui like the website admin for pages where you can activate.

Activating a page/folder/asset does not activate sub-pages/folders/assets. This can cause confusion especially when working with folders.

Generally if you need to activate a tree the best way is to use the tree activation utility

Comment: I'd avoid activating anything under /apps - this will NOT remove any files deleted from the source. Use content packages instead.

Comment: @kfaerber Activating the /apps/<mysite> worked wonders. I am surprised why this detail is not mentioned in the tutorials !! 50 rep !! THANKS !! :)

Comment: @antonyh You are correct, content packages is a better way to maintain code on the publish instance. For a first push of code, which is what the problem was, activation is fine.

Comment: Also, as an aside: compiled classes (including JSP) go in /var/classes  - it seems that the package manager knows to do something to these when deployment takes place that doesn't happen (in my experience) when code is activated from author to publish. You may need to clear this branch sometimes if code changes don't stick.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've ever seen this is when the code is not installed. That would be the first thing that I'd check. Go to (assuming you have your publisher on port 4503)

```
http://localhost:4503/crx/de
```

You should have your the code in /apps and you should be able to find the content page in /content too.

The reason this happens is that the sling:resourceType property points to a component that doesn't exist so it uses the default which is an empty output.

Comment: I checked the crx/de on 4503 and it contains none of my changes. The template, the component, the pages, nothing. The replication consolde on 4502 , though, shows the page as activated. What can I do in this case ?

Comment: You can create a package that contains your code on the author server and activate that so that it is deployed on the publish server

Comment: If the publisher:4503 contains the content but not the template/code/components then a package will solve this. If the content isn't there either... how bizarre. I'd want to check two things at this stage: 1. does the activated page have the replication metadata on the author (which is will if it is reporting as activated in the author interface), and 2. what is the target for the replication agent? Where is it replicating to if not the published?

Comment: Also, it's possible to set a replication agent as disabled - this would cause it to silently skip that agent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the code to both the environments (author as well as publish). This way both the environments will have the same copy of source code installed in the form of cq5 packages and felix bundles. Then if you create a new page or drop any component on any existing page, it will appear the same on publish environment after activating the same either through 'Activate Page' link in sidekick or through replication tree activation page.